# Alternate definitions of Fourier Algebra

Tags: harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

---

### **Background:**

---

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, with left regular representation $\lambda:G\to B(L^{2}(G))$.

The **Fourier algebra** $A(G)$ is typically defined to be the space of functions of the form:

$f(s) = \langle \lambda(s)\zeta,\eta\rangle$ for some $\zeta,\eta \in L^{2}(G)$

and the **Fourier-Stieltjes algebra** $B(G)$ is defined to be the space of all functions of the form

$f(s) = \langle \pi(s)\zeta,\eta\rangle$ for some $\zeta,\eta \in H_{\pi}$, for some continuous unitary representation $(\pi,H_{\pi})$ of $G$.

---

### **Body:**

---

I am reading some lecture notes on these algebras which instead do the following:

For any continuous unitary representation $(\pi,H_{\pi})$ of $G$, define
$\pi_{\zeta,\eta}:G\to\mathbb{C}$ by $\pi_{\zeta,\eta}(s) = \langle\pi(s)\zeta,\eta\rangle$ and set

$$F_{\pi} = span\{\pi_{\zeta,\eta}:\zeta,\eta\in H_{\pi}\}$$

Then define the Fourier-Stieltjes algebra to be $B(G) = \bigcup_{\pi} F_{\pi}$ where the union is taken over all continuous unitary representations of $G$.

Then the space $A_{\pi}$ is defined to be the closure of $F_{\pi}$ in $B(G)$; and the Fourier Algebra $A(G)$ is defined be the space $A_{\lambda}$.

---

### **My questions:**

---

1) Clearly the two definitions of $B(G)$ are identical.  But with the latter definition of $A(G)$ we've added both a linear span and closure in the norm topology.  I'm going to hazard a guess that it is a very non-trivial result that these definitions are equivalent, and the advantage to using the latter definition is to be able to avoid the issue entirely.

2) Assuming that my guess is correct, is this also true for other $\pi\neq\lambda$?  In other words, is $A_{\pi}$ simply the space of all functions of the form

$f(s) = \langle \lambda(s)\zeta,\eta\rangle$ for some $\zeta,\eta \in H_{\pi}$

or is the span and closure necessary for these other spaces $A_{\pi}$?.

Many thanks in advance for any clarification I can get!

Comment: I don't understand really what is $\langle \lambda(s)\zeta,\eta\rangle$. You want to avoid the Haar measure ? But are you going to prove it exists ?

Comment: Left regular means it is well-behaved under translation of $G$, so it will be isomorphic to the algebra of $L^2(G)$ under convolution with respect to the Haar measure ?

Comment: You need to pick a Haar measure to make sense of $\langle \lambda(s)\zeta,\eta\rangle$, which is the inner product of $\lambda(s)\zeta$ and $\eta$.  But I'm not sure what you're saying in either of your comments.

Comment: I really meant that your definition are cryptic for those who didn't read this book. What is natural and easy to visualize is the Haar measure and the convolution algebra.

Comment: I'm not sure what book you are referring to.  Haar measure is the generalization of Lebesgue measure.  Convolution can be thought of as a sort of "intertwining" of two functions.  If either of two functions $f$ or $g$ have property $(P)$, then often so does $f*g$.

If my definitions are cryptic, it is because they reflect the target audience of the question I am asking.  I felt that this question was a bit too basic to ask on mathoverflow.net, but anyone who could answer this question definitively would not need anymore background information than I gave.

Comment: I have no problem with the Haar measure and the convolution, I was asking how to interpret $\langle \lambda(s)\zeta,\eta\rangle$ which is cryptic !

Comment: It is the inner product of the function $\zeta(s^{-1}\cdot)$ and $\eta$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes to part (1) and no to (2), but I do not have a proof.

If anyone can do better, I'd happily award the bounty.

**Edit**:  The bounty has expired, and the question is no longer urgent, but if someone could give an example that establishes that (2) fails I will eagerly start another bounty and award it to them (as long as that does not violate the rules of this site).